# Reading OkHttp ResponseBody data asynchronously

Tags: okhttp

I'm using OkHttp's `Call#enqueue` to issue a couple dozen HTTP requests in parallel.  In my callback, I'm given an `Response` with a `ResponseBody`.  Because I have several requests in flight, I'd like to read data from the `ResponseBody`'s `source()` without blocking.  Is there some way to do that?

For example, if suppose there are 324 bytes available in a given `ResponseBody`, is there some way to read those bytes and then wait asynchronously for more data to be available (potentially reading data from other `ResponseBody` objects for other in-flight requests in the interim)?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33447787/2603965

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope! OkHttp doesn't yet offer anything that flexible. You might want to look at Parallel Universe, which has hooked up OkHttp to fibers.